# WPF Toolbar Background property ignored in style

Tags: wpf

Setting the Background property in a ToolBar style has no effect when the ToolBar is contained in a ToolBarTray. Other properties e.g. Margin work. Setting the property directly in the ToolBar works but as I want a LinearGradientBrush the aim is to encapsulate this in the style. It also works if the ToolBar is removed from the tray, but I need the tray to make it vertical. What am I missing?

That's quick! I have tried it with and without a style for the tray, also telling the tray it has null style but it has no effect either way. At present the tray has no style. The mark up is:

```
    <Style x:Key="MyToolBarStyle" TargetType="ToolBar">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="18"/>
        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
        <Setter Property="UseLayoutRounding" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Background">
            <Setter.Value>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0" MappingMode="RelativeToBoundingBox">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF70150"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF0986EE" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF1F060D" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFE680AC"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

The toolbar (with the button list shortened) is:

```
        <ToolBarTray Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical" Grid.RowSpan="50" Margin="5,0">
            <ToolBar x:Name="MyToolBar" Style="{StaticResource MyToolBarStyle}" Header="Main menu">
                <Button x:Name="New_Network" Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="New_Net_Click" Content="New Network"/>
            </ToolBar>
        </ToolBarTray>
```

Comment: Are you having any style for ToolBarTray? Please post what you have tried.

Comment: It's weird. It's a problem with `ToolBarTray.Orientation`. because when set to Horizontal it works!

Comment: Out of interest it is just the same if you create the toolbartray and its toolbar in code, referencing the style - the background in the style is ignored if the tray is set vertical but works if you make it horizontal or define it in the code.